# How to disable jQuery validation for a specific Submit button?

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I have two buttons, one for Next and one for SAVE 
when clicking Next I would like to let jQuery do its validation, but when SAVE is CLICKED jQuery will not do its validation. Are there event handlers for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$("#nextButtonId").click(validateFunction);
$("#saveButtonId").click(saveFunction);
```

Something like this would work

Answer (score 7):

The jQuery Validation plugin will automatically capture/validate on any `button` or `input` (within the `<form></form>` container) with `type="submit"` and ignore any with `type="button"`.

```
<button type="submit">NEXT</button>
<button type="button">SAVE</button>
```

OR

```
<input type="submit" value="NEXT" />
<input type="button" value="SAVE" />
```

---

Alternatively, adding a `class="cancel"` to the button will cause the plugin to ignore it.

```
<button type="submit">NEXT</button>
<button type="submit" class="cancel">SAVE</button>
```

OR

```
<input type="submit" value="NEXT" />
<input type="submit" class="cancel" value="SAVE" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it's found in the jquery.validate.js
 `// allow suppresing validation by adding a cancel class to the submit button
   this.find("input, button").filter(".cancel").click(function() {
    validator.cancelSubmit = true;
   });`

Answer (score -1):

Set up two functions `next()` and `save()` where you would use `validate()` in `next()` and skip the validation in `save()`.

If you provided some code we could help you further.